# JQGrid with filter search by name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, jqgrid

How to add filter in JQGrid search by name document like in picture

Example JQGrid:

[image: Example JQGrid]

Comment: Please add a little more information about what it is you've tried already?

Comment: Please share your code and also try to create a `jsFiddle` link with the exact problem.

Comment: I make it from codeigniter from controller then call the existing library. .what can i share because I did not build from start just continue. .to load from controller call in this file **assets/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.jd**